# How to receive soap request from codeigniter controller?

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter, soap

How I can receive a soap request in my controller? For your convenient I am sharing the sample soap format. From this I need to get "message" field. Can you please suggest me any solution.

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <ns1:NotifySOAPHeader xmlns:ns1="http://www.huawei.com.cn/schema/common/v2_1">
         <ns1:timeStamp>111029084631570</ns1:timeStamp>             <ns1:traceUniqueID>100001200101110623021721000011</ns1:traceUniqueID>
      </ns1:NotifySOAPHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns2:notifySmsReception xmlns:ns2="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/notification/v2_2/local">
         <ns2:correlator>00001</ns2:correlator>
         <ns2:message>
            <message>Hello world</message>
            <dateTime>2010-08-09T00:00:00.000+08:00</dateTime>
         </ns2:message>
      </ns2:notifySmsReception>
   </soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Doing SOAP is not the best place to start learning a framework. Definitely do the tutorial in codeigniter manual first. then work through this tutorial for soap in ci - http://www.azmeer.info/nusoap-with-codeigniter/

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have started work with Codeigniter with other projects. But yes I am working with SOAP in Codeigniter recently. I have checked your given tutorial. I did not find my solution with this tutorial. Can you please suggest me any other solution? It will help me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: I think this isn't a CI problem , rather than a PHP issue, What did you try so far to use this kind of soap request, Which version of PHP are u using ?
Do you use a soapservice which requires NTLM Authentication etc.etc. you've to provide us details in order to answer your question...

Comment: Start building and trying things out. Get errors and try and figure out what is causing them. Then come back to stack - with code you have tried - with specific errors you have not been able to get an answer to - and then someone will be able to help you.